# SQL Calculation to 2 decimal places

Tags: sql

I've got a simple calculation (910 / 28 = 3.5) and I'm trying to perform this in a SQL query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), (910 / 28),2) AS average
```

But the answer is coming out at 32.00, I'm obviously missing something simple could someone spare a moment to point out my error please?

Thanks,
C

Comment: It calculates (910 / 28) using integer maths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), (910.0 / 28)) AS average
```

By taking the quotient as `910.0 / 28` SQL Server will retain decimal precision.  Then, make your cast to a decimal with two places.  By the way, as far as I know `CONVERT` typically takes just two parameters when converting a number to decimal.

Answer (score 2):

we can use this query for dynamic value from table:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), (cast (910 as decimal))/ 28) AS average
```

It will give the desire output

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if this applies to your database, but in [Trino SQL](https://trino.io/) (a sort of database middleware layer), I find adding a decimal point followed by two zeros to any of two operands in this query (e.g., `select 910.00/23  AS average` or `select 910/23.00  AS average`) returns a non-integer value (`39.57`, instead of `39`).

Adding 3 zeros after the decimal (`select 910.000/23  AS average`) returns a 3-decimal place result (`39.565`), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query...

```
  SELECT CAST(910 AS decimal(5,2)) / CAST(28 AS decimal(5,2)) as average
```

Answer (score -1):

Try use this

```
select cast(round(910/28.0,2) as numeric(36,2)) AS average
```